# jQuery - How to calculate width of li floats

Tags: jquery, html, css

Let's say i got a list looking like this:

```
<ul style="width:980px;">
     <li style="display:block; float:left;">Lorem ipsum</li>
     <li style="display:block; float:left;">Lorem ipsum #2</li>
     <li style="display:block; float:left;">Lorem ipsum #3</li>
     <li style="display:block; float:left;">Lorem ipsum #4</li>
     <li style="display:block; float:left;">Lorem ipsum #5</li>
     <li style="display:block; float:left;">Lorem ipsum #6</li>
</ul>
```

How would i find the correct width of each li in this list?

Currently i tried to loop the li's and then print out the outerWidth, innerWidth and width.

All seems to return 0 as width.

Got any ideas on how to get the correct with of the elements without having to calculate the length of the string?

Comment: count letters, multiply it by constant, add some additional space.

Comment: Your approach is correct, but are you sure you do it *after* the DOM is loaded? Could you post your code?

Comment: create a jsfiddle that replicates your issue

Comment: not really on topic but...Is there any reason to put the same css rule on every li element instead of, for example, giving a class to the ul?

Comment: @microspino It is an example. If i just wrote some class'es you would have no idea what they would do.

Comment: @All - Thanks for all the suggestions. Found out that because the container in which the list was had a display none it could not calculate the width of the elements. I will reward the one with the most documented and correct answer with thumbs up and marked at answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the width method. eg.

```
$('li').each(function() {
    alert( $(this).width() );
});
```

This requires:

- The DOM to be loaded (i.e. run the code from a ready handler)
- The elements to be visible on the page

  - The element itself cannot be `display: none`
  - And all parent elements must be visible

http://jsfiddle.net/DvNf5/

Comment: @DannieHansen - Can you produce a jsfiddle that reproduces your problem? That will make it easier to see what's wrong.

Comment: Returns `79, 99, ...` for me. What browser are you using? And are you running your script after the DOM has loaded?

Comment: Read the comment on the main post :) Thanks, was entirely my mistake. Been sitting with the issue for like 4 hours straight. We all got our blond moments.

Answer (score 1):

This code is returning widths for me -

```
$("ul > li").each(function() {
    alert($(this).width());
});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/CdyYa/

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
    $("li").each(function(){
       console.log( this.offsetWidth ); 
    });

//79 99 99 99 99 99
```

http://jsfiddle.net/63nxL/

Comment: Darn it :) That returns 0 as well.

Comment: @DannieHansen, then your page does something different from jsfiddle :P

Comment: Looks like if i turn block on and off using chromes editor(HTML) and then execute the function to fix the width one more it works. But no matter when or where i execute the fix with in my JS it won't return correct widths.

Answer (score 0):

How about, instead of `display: block; float: left;`,

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: Tried that as well- No luck either.

Comment: Works for me on all modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery...
http://jsfiddle.net/y4X8S/  (the fiddle uses console.log instead of alert)

```
$( function(){
    $('li').each( function( i,el ){
        alert( $(el).width() );   
    } );
});
```